# Split the string on a delimiter based on conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a string similar to below

```
var str = '1;2;3;{"A",B};4;6;{"C","D"}'
```

I want to convert the str into array seperated by ";"

```
var array = [str.split(';')];
```

It is converted to --> `["1","2","3","{"A",B}","4","6","{"C","D"}"]`

But I need a array similar to this -->`[1,2,3,{"A",B},4,6,{"C","D"}]`

All the numbers should be as numeric and string as strings.I know it can be done using loop, but is there an easy way of doing it, because the string in reality is very big with almost 500-600 values.

Comment: `[1,2,3,{"A",B},4,6,{"C","D"}]` is not a valid array or object.

Comment: Your example output isn't valid as `B` is a string and so must be quoted, and also `{"A",B}` and `{"C","D"}` are not valid objects.

Comment: You probably fail to show your approach or unrealistic approach to output.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the input is a number and convert it and to remove the other stuff convert it back to string

```
var str = '1;2;3;{"A",B};4;6;{"C","D"}'
str.split(';').map(x => {
        if (!isNaN(x)) {
            return parseInt(x, 10)
        }
        return x;
    }).join(',')
    .replace("\"{", "{")
    .replace("\"}", "}")
```

example string: `1,2,3,{"A",B},4,6,{"C","D}`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Is there any way I can remove the double quotes from the non numeric value as mentioned in my question.

Comment: @CrazyCoder ztadic91 is right with his code but your approach to showing output probably wrong.

Comment: @Dipakchavda I understand..Thanks for the reply anyway :)